# active anchor tag background color

Tags: html, css, tiles

I have jsp page built with struts2 tiles which has vertical Menu on the left hand side. Upon selecting a Menu I want to keep the background of the selected menu's background color to white. The action will be smiler to tab selection. I have googled for solution but no luck. The effect is working for hover action but the background color is not staying consistently.

Below is my html code with css.

```
ul.v_menu li a
{   
display: block;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align:left;    
color: #fff;
}
ul.v_menu li a:hover,ul.v_menu li a.active
{
color:black;
background: white;
}
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="v_menu">

        <li><a href="#">DashBoard</a></li>
        <li><tags:a action="viewIncomeGrid">Income</tags:a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Expense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Payee</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Tiles:

```
  <definition name="myBaseLayout" template="/MyBaseLayout.jsp">
       <put-attribute name="title" value="M-Manager"/>
       <put-attribute name="headerMenu" value="/Banner.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="vMenu" value="/vMenu.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/Body.jsp"/>
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp"/>
   </definition>
```

[image: apache tiles Vertical Menu's page layout]

The required behaviour is working for the `<li><a href="#">DashBoard</a></li>` menu item as there is no **action** mapped to this anchor tag. But If we map any action to the link and upon clicking the link the entire page is getting refreshed and the right side body part is having the desired page but the left hand side menu for which I have set the **hover,active,focus** behaviours either by css or by jQuery are getting lost. How to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/gdgjpv0b/

Comment: You have to give the selected menu item a class like "active" and style it like you want. When you click a menu item you need to remove the class active from the item selected before and give it to the new item. This would be no problem if you have multiple html / php /.. files for your pages. Otherwise you will need some javascript code, if you need something like tabs.

Comment: @NenadVracar: Yes exactly. But as I mentioned I am using tiles. So when I select menu item the right hand side part(BODY) is filled with some other page as a result the active effect( background: white) is getting lost. that is my issue

Comment: WIth CSS `:active` and `:focus` when you remove focus, active state is lost (when you click somewhere else), so you have to do this with JS (i am using JQuery), so try this https://jsfiddle.net/gdgjpv0b/1/, i am not sure if this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/panks_josh/1gxq8se6/

```
ul.v_menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.v_menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
ul.v_menu li a:focus {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

Please use this :Focus instead of :Active,, will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

find the working fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/s8hLsogc/

i add some tricky selectors to catch every think under lis like so :

```
li:hover *
```

Comment: As mention by Nenad Vracar https://jsfiddle.net/gdgjpv0b/ 
is what I am looking for. But because of the tiles the effect is getting lost as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

```
ul.v_menu li a:active
    {
        color:black;
        background: white;
    }
```

Comment: If you see my code I am using the same code but the required behaviour is not working as I mention in my previous comments

Comment: you are using :Active and I am using :Focus,, if you see my code above

Comment: Yes I agree.. but I have tried with focus as well, as per the suggestion by the user Nenad Vracar(1st comment of my post). Still it is not working.